# How can I make this useful JSFiddle i found work on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

Okay, I found this JSfiddle to add another input field on click and when I copied the code from JSFiddle into my site, HTML, Javascript, and necessary Jquery.  After much research, I can't seem to figure out why the result is always nothing.  its quite depressing actually.  Let me throw you the code and see if you can tell me where I'm being dumb.  xD

here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tzpg4/4/) I want.

HTML:

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt"     size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a     href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

I made sure to put the jquery after the custom JS file, I wrapped my JavaScript with $(document).ready()
I'm just not sure what to try next.  Please help!!!  thank you!

Comment: Did you mean put jquery before your custom file?

Comment: yes, thanks.  I stated that backwards

Comment: Did you wrap your html in the standard tags? The ones html and body and do you have the head tags

Comment: yes, all that looks good.

Comment: What errors does your console give you

Comment: I tried out using your code, and it seemed to work perfectly fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/3rU8g5RvsWKNC1m5WDGe?p=preview

Comment: no errors come up.  I just press the "add another input box," button, still nothing occurs

Comment: hmmm, well any ideas why it wouldn't work once I put it on my own page locally?  I see that it works great on that link you sent me

Comment: Have you tried deleting the second jquery link it's a very old version of jquery you want to use the newer 1.11.3

Comment: okay, I deleted the second jQuery which is the older one and the result is now when I click the "add another input box" link, it refreshes the page

Comment: Can you link us to your site that you're testing on? We'll figure out what's going on

Comment: @WebWilliam: what is the owl-carousel? Haven't you included the script for the same?

Comment: the owl-carousel is actually just bones from another site I created and then copied to give me a jumpstart on this one.  Did you find it in the custom.js file?

Comment: @WebWilliam: Seems like that is throwing an error, saying "owl.owlCarousel is not a function". And maybe you could try including this code inside the same, document. ready.

Comment: I don't know why, but removing those bones ( the owl carousel script) made it work.  Can anyone teach me why so I don't make a similar mistake again?

Comment: See, since javascript is read line-by-line, it encountered ur "owl carousel" code first. It wasn't able to find any such function, and the code beyond that isn't read after that. So, the rest events weren't binding to your link. And that's why the link wasn't working. So, you should always look up into the console, if you're getting any such errors.

Comment: @WebWilliam: I am posting the solution as an answer, so anybody facing such issue may get the answer.

Comment: ah, I see.  Thank you.  I really appreciate you taking the time to explain.  I love this site and how helpful the community can be.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the website had a missing module, called "owl-carousel". Because of that, JS was encountering an error, and the events weren't binding to the link, which was responsible for creating input boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You have jQuery listed twice. You only need one of them. This will cause problems:

> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"</script>
> ```

Also, you mention **`<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`** but is it uploaded to your server? If not you can use a CDN like this:

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
> <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: the bootstrap script is uploaded to my server and seems to work alright.  The first Jquery link is the one provided by bootstrap and says is necessary for bootstrap 3 while the second is the one that i found on the JSfiddle i wanted to use.  I went ahead and deleted the first jQuery and tried it out anyway, but it didn't change anything, sadly

Comment: Um it probably would have been better to keep the first jquery link and delete the second the second is a more outdated version of jquery

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('#yourObjectId').live('click', function());` I recommend you to use:

`$('#yourObjectId').on('click', function() { //put your codes here });`
or
`$('#yourObjectId').click(function() { //put your codes here });`

`.live('click')` is deprecated, because you are using `jQuery1.11.3`. If you only using `jQuery1.4.3` or previous versions, it should be works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1.remove: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2.change the js like this and place it at the top of you custom.js file:

```
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

        $('body').on('click','#addScnt',function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                i++;

        });

        $('body').on('click','#remScnt',function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }

        });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/14890/

Comment: it sadly didn't change the situation.  :/

Comment: nope.  The link just keeps refreshing the page but doing nothing else.